# A duplicate field name "..." was found

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am doing a migration from Sharepoint 2010 to 2013 and get constantly an error by deploying a solution:

**A duplicate field name "..." was found.**

Sharepoint claims that these fields are already used, although this is not the case. I have read some articles where people write, that there are reserved words in Sharepoint 2013, that cannot be used for field names.

Is there a complete list of these reserved words? I have just already spent 2 days changing field names and I can see no end of the migration process...

Some of the fields Sharepoint complained about were: Name, FirstName, Duration, EventType, Role etc. Is it possible that all these words are reserved or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: do we have any answer for this?

Comment: I haven't found such a list; the field names that I found out are:
City,  Name, FirstName, FullName, Company, Role, Subject, Country, Duration, EventType, Language